# Problem loading Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I had a local application in Visual Studio 2010 with Crystal Reports, after install the app in another computer when I want to show a report it throws the following message:

*System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: An error has occurred while attempting to load the Crystal Reports runtime. Either the Crystal Reports registry key permissions are insufficient, or the Crystal Reports runtime is not installed correctly. Please install the appropriate Crystal Reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86, x64, or Itanium) required.  Please go to http://www.businessobjects.com/support for more information*

In my Setup I included all the Crystal Reports dll so I don't have idea what it presents this problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

See this [blog post](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/weblogs?blog=/pub/wlg/14514) for details on how to install and deploy Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010.

The blog post also contains links (at the top of the blog) for details on the runtime and licensing options.

HTH